# How do I hide a button in html?

Tags: html, button

I am a beginner in HTML. How would I make a button that would hide itself when clicked using JavaScript? This is the code I have already, missing a line.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <body>
        <button type="button" onclick="delete()" = ;>Hello</button>
        <script>
            var delete = function(){
            //hide button
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

delete is a keyword in js. Use a different name

```
onclick="deleteThis(this)"



var deleteThis = function(elem){
        elem.style.display = 'none';
        // elem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
};
```

Answer (score 1):

**First** add button **'id'**

```
    <button type="button" id='theid' onclick="delete()" = ;>Hello</button>
```

**Then** go to the **`script`** part

```
    <script>
        var delete = function(){
        document.getElementById('theid').style.display="none";  // for hide button
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

See documentation for [Style Visibility](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_visibility.asp).

Add an ID to your button like this:

```
<button id="my_button" type="button" onclick="delete()" = ;>Hello</button>
```

Then in your JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("my_button").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<title>WisdmLabs</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>

</style>

</head>

<body>

<button type="button" id="myButton" onclick="hideMe()">Click Me To Hide</button>
<script>
function hideMe(){
 $("#myButton").hide();
}
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Feel free to ask any doubts or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

No need to write too much code, I have edited your code , and you can get the effect just like that,,,

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <body>
        <button type="button" onclick="this.style.display='none'">Hello</button>
    </body>
</html>
```